# Make an excel workbook in java version 1.4

Tags: java, excel

I have to create an excel sheet with number of rows more than 65536. I have to code in java version 1.4 only(Project constraint).

I used the `HSSF` API as it is supported in version `1.4`.I tried making workbook using `jxl` API also. But it also gave me the error that maximum rows limit is reached. I have 100000 rows. `XSSF` API is not supported in `1.4` version.

Can anyone suggest any different way to make the excel workbook that can create rows up to 100000 in version 1.4.

Comment: Can't you upgrade java? [1.4 is really old](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#J2SE_1.4_.28February_6.2C_2002.29) and using it is 1/ a security issue 2/ a pain

Comment: I know.. :( But this is the version of my server in my company. And I am not allowed to upgrade it. :(